# How to add new request values to call a function in same controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

How to call a function `save(Request $request)` from another function in the same Controller ?

```
foreach ($_parts as $key => $part_data) {
    $request->item = $part;
    $request->qty = $part_data->quantity;
    $call = $this->save($request);
}
```

**My save function:**

```
public function save(Request $request) {
        dd($request->all());
}
```

The `dd($request->all())` returns `[]`.

Comment: typo?   `dd($request->all);` `dd($request->all()) `

Comment: Does `dd($request)` return null?

Comment: I don't think the attributes you create on the request will be in the `$request->all()`, because they are not in the original request. In my opinion you should not change the request object that way. Also, you overwrite `$request->item` in every loop.

Comment: I would like to add the attributes with original request in calling function.

Comment: @SowndharKumarR Even if you add the attributes, the are overwritten in every loop of the foreach. there is a function to add attributes. `$request->request->add()`if i'm not mistaking. But really, you shouldn't. I really wonder why you don't pass the $_parts as a second parameter...

Comment: Thanks `$request->request->add()` is working.